# HTML5 drawImage slow on Chrome

Tags: performance, html, canvas, rendering, drawimage

I'm having some real difficulty with offscreen rendering with HTML5!
The code I have written runs perfectly fine with Firefox, using drawImage on canvas elements draws smooth images and does so very quickly.

However, using Chrome 21, the drawImage performance is just terrible. I'm unable to see where I'm going wrong.

Here is a jsfiddle with some sample code:
http://jsfiddle.net/DXgum/3/

In Firefox, I can get about 60fps, chrome only delivers a framerate of 10fps.
The performance does not differ if I'm using in-dom canvas elements or not-in-dom.

Rendering without buffering on Chrome is faster than Firefox, so I'm actually not sure why Chrome is having such a problem with drawImage.

Any help or light into the matter would be greatly appreciated!

System Information:

- Windows 7 32bit
- Intel QX9650
- Nvidia GTS 250
- 4GB DDR2 RAM
- Chrome Version: 21.0.1180.60 m
- Firefox Version: 14.0.1

Comment: I've tested on Safari 6, MBP (Core I7 2.4 MHz) OSX 10.7.4 and got 125 - 149 fps. Are you sure the problem is the `drawImage` function and not maybe the `Math` stuff? If drawing in itself is faster on chrome, then probably something else is hampering performance. Try using the web inspector and do a sample of your JavaScript or rendering to see where it is stuck.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to check.
Unfortunately I'm pretty sure its the drawImage Method, I did as you suggested and removed everything from the loop that wasn't needed.


Here is the jsfiddle with the updated code:
http://jsfiddle.net/DXgum/10/

Interestingly, if I reduce the size of the canvas (to 100,100), Chrome now renders the images at 142fps:
http://jsfiddle.net/DXgum/11/

So somehow it must be rendering the entire canvas on each drawImage call?I don't understand.

Comment: Actually, a main canvas size of anything over 256x256 has poor performance. Could this then have something to do with the GPU acceleration?

Comment: I [changed a small bit](http://jsfiddle.net/DXgum/12/) and now get 250fps. Maybe the culprit is that you save the `context` x1000 and then use `objects[i].context` which in turn has to be rendered before being used in the `drawImage` method. This is just a wild guess but might be worth a shot.

Comment: You could try using an offscreen buffer canvas. Try painting into a canvas which is not in the DOM and then use draw image once for the whole buffer on your actual canvas. Calling `drawIamge` has to trigger a render, at least internally, since it needs to recalculate the pixel values. The question now is, is the rendering at fault or that Chrome is pushing the pixels to the screen. Anything more is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: I'm not sure about is being the fault of objects[i].context, I've read reports that drawing 1 image has dramatic performance boosts over drawing multiple images. But 1000 instances of the same image would defeat the point of rendering 1000 objects to the screen, not all the objects will look the same. However you are right that it increases the performance, as I've noticed that on my machine also.
I tried drawing everything to an offscreen buffer like you suggested, but that doesn't seem to have any affect on the performance. So I'm still a little stuck!

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for years. One version of chrome it's fine, the next release it's slow again... My ultimate solution is a little hacky, but it works.

Using your fiddle I was able to determine for sure that performance massively dropped off if the size of the canvas is <= 256.

My canvas was 200 x 200.

I simply made my canvas 258 x 258, change all the math to accommodate the new dimensions and used the CSS zoom property on the canvas's wrapper div to shrink the appearance of the canvas down to the approximate original size.

Doing this, I went from 30-40 fps to a nice steady 60.